# Prove the existence of one and only one isomorphism between products of objects of a category

Tags: category-theory

Let $ \mathscr{C} $ be a category, $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $ two objects of $ \mathscr{C} $ and $ (P,p_1,p_2) $ and $ (Q,q_1,q_2) $ two products of $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $. Prove that there is one and only one isomorphism $ \psi:Q\to P $ such that $ p_1\circ \psi=q_1 $ and $ p_2\circ \psi=q_2 $.

Here is my attempt to answer:

Since $ Q $ is an object in $ \mathscr{C} $, there exists a unique morphism $ \psi:Q\to P=X_1\times X_2 $ such that $ p_1\circ \psi=q_1 $ and $ p_2\circ \psi=q_2 $ by the definition of products. Similarly, there exists a unique morphism $ \psi':P\to Q=X_1\times X_2 $ such that $ q_1\circ \psi'=p_1 $ and $ q_2\circ \psi'=p_2 $. Hence
$$ q_1=p_1\circ \psi=(q_1\circ \psi')\circ \psi,  $$
$$ q_2=p_2\circ \psi=(q_2\circ \psi')\circ \psi,  $$
$$ p_1=q_1\circ \psi'=(p_1\circ \psi)\circ \psi'  $$
and
$$ p_2=q_2\circ \psi'=(p_2\circ \psi)\circ \psi'  $$
Can I conclude that $ \psi'=\psi^{-1} $, the inverse of $ \psi $ and that $ \psi $ therefore is an isomorphism?

Comment: You need to give more details: what have you tried? where do you get stuck? (Did you open any textbook about category theory? That kind of proof is often given in the first chapters.)

Comment: @Pece. I have posted my attempt to answer now.

Comment: That's better !

Comment: @Pece In which books can I find the proof of this exercise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your almost there! You found a good candidate $\psi$, and a candidate for its inverse $\psi'$. So all you have to show is that $\psi'\psi = \mathrm{id}$ and $\psi\psi' = \mathrm{id}$.

Now, rewriting a little bit your equations through associativity of composition, you also proved that $f = \psi'\psi$ is an arrow $Q \to Q$ satisfying:
$$ q_1 = q_1 f \quad \text{and} \quad q_2 = q_2 f $$
Do you know such another $f$? If so, what does it tell you on $f$? 
(*Hint: use the universal property of the product $Q$*.)

Symmetrically you proved that $g = \psi\psi'$ is an arrow $P \to P$ satisfying:
$$ p_1 = p_1 g \quad \text{and} \quad p_2 = p_2 g $$
Play the same game on $g$ with the universal property of the product $P$.

Comment: Aha. Another such $f$ is of course the identity $id$ mapping $Q$ to itself. Using the universal property of the product $Q$, we see that this $f$ is unique, so $f=id_Q$. Similarly, $g=id_P$. Done?

Comment: @Barbara Here you go ;)